How does the all-knowing God and human's free will interact in the physical world in Islam?
From my very basic understanding, in Islam, everything that has happened and that will happen is already known by God. Yet it also says at the same time that humans have free will. I don't get how this works in detail. If God knows everything and is the source of all actions, then we are like cogs in a giant wheel and have no free will. Yet if humans have free will, then God is not a part of at least some parts of the universe (such as human minds)? But God is a part of everything, God is not absent from any part of the universe, so I don't get how these two ideas can coexist.
The only way I can imagine it is like a rat in a wheel. The rat is in a cage, running along in a spinning wheel. Inside the wheel, they are free to run and run and do whatever they want. But they are not causing anything outside of the wheel to happen, so in that sense their actions are not tied to the rest of the system. But that's as far as that metaphor goes.
I have heard some people say that "well God controls the spiritual world, while humans control the physical world. The physical world is a test bed for how humans act, and after death they will be judged for their actions in the spiritual world, and a corresponding reward or punishment chosen for them." Sort of thing. But even then, that is saying that God is only present in the spiritual dimension, not the physical. It is as if God carved out a space (physical space) where God is not present. And only interacts through messages or something. But that contradicts other ideas which say God is omnipresent in the universe. So I'm not sure how this works.
Can you please explain how the concepts of human free will and an all-knowing God can coexist, from the perspective of Islam?
